# Angularjs ControllerAs replacement for $watchCollection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been in the processing of refactoring my angularjs app to use controllerAs and wanted to see if I could get rid of all $scope.$watch functions.  I have managed this by defining properties with getters and setters and that has worked great.  Where I am stuck is a replacement for $watchCollection.  As an example I have a directive with a property defined called "params".  this is an object with child properties.  Before I could use $scope.$watch('params',function(){...},true) or use $watchCollection.  Now the setter does not get called since the actual object is not being set when a child parameter is changed.  Below is the solution I have come up with but am hoping there is something better.  Also, I know I can still use $watch and $watchCollection if I need to.  Just seeing if there is a way to avoid it. The params property is dynamic so will not know the child properties in advance.

```
var dynamicVariables = {};
function defineChildProperty(obj,i){
    if(!dynamicVariables.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      dynamicVariables[i] = obj[i];
    }
    Object.defineProperty(obj,i,{
      get:function(){return dynamicVariables[i];},
      set:function(val){
        if(obj[i] === val){
          return;
        }
        dynamicVariables[i] = val;
        fetchChart();
      }
    });
  }

  function getChildProperties(obj){
    for(var i in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        defineChildProperty(obj,i);
      }
    }
  }
```